# Change event not firing alert

Tags: javascript

I have a select with an ID of `vat` and I try to do something when the select is changed, but it is not working. I tried several solutions mentioned here at SO, but the alert is not showing. So any idea what is going wrong? Here is my code:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  $('#vat').change(function(){
    alert("hello");
  });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Other action in the same js file do work, e.g.

```
  $('#rate').blur(function() {
    recalculateAmounts();
  });
```

This is the HTML:

```
<select id="vat" name="vat">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="2">6%</option>
  <option value="3">19%</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="1">21%</option>
</select>
```

Comment: or add in a jsfiddle.net

Comment: why its covered in var ready function??

Comment: Wrap it inside document.ready function

Comment: Just working .http://jsfiddle.net/79mnE/3/

Comment: I see the code is just working, it must be some blocking javascript elsewhere.

Comment: Pfff, after a restart of Chrome everything worked fine :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML must be having some problem otherwise it will always work fine. See this -

http://jsfiddle.net/5X2VY/

`Same code` as yours